# Parallel Anti diagonal 'for' loop?

Tags: cuda

I have an N x N square matrix of integers (which is stored in the device as a 1-d array for convenience).

I'm implementing an algorithm which requires the following to be performed:

There are 2N anti diagonals in this square. (anti - diagonals are parallel lines from top edge to left edge and right edge to bottom edge)

I need a for loop with 2N iterations with each iteration computing one anti-diagonal starting from the top left and ending at bottom right.

In each iteration, all the elements in that anti-diagonal must run parallelly.

Each anti-diagonal is calculated based on the values of the previous anti-diagonal.

So, how do I index the threads with this requirement in CUDA?

Comment: Show the code you already wrote. Nobody is going to write all for you.

Comment: @JackOLantern: are you mixing edges and corners? I agree the question is confused but it sounds to me like he wants to start with the anti-diagonal in the top-left corner (one element, index 0), then the next anti-diagonal (two elements, index 1 and N), then the next (2, N+1, 2N) and so on to the bottom-right corner. Within an anti-diagonal the elements can be treated in parallel. Assuming the matrix is large the inefficiencies (block size vs anti-diagonal length) may be amortised. However I may have misunderstood since there are 2N-1 anti-diagonals not 2N. It needs clarification.

Comment: @Tom I think your interpretation is correct. I apologize for my previous comment which I have now removed.

Comment: @Tom Out of curiosity, the question seems a re-issue with very similar sentences of a question posted in 2008 in the NVIDIA forum [Parallel Anti diagonal 'for' loop ?](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/393607/parallel-anti-diagonal-39-for-39-loop-/) and the comment by Lorenz Meyer seems a re-issue of the first comment to that question :-)

Comment: @JackOLantern: Wow, good catch! It's almost identical and yet from 5 years ago...

Comment: @Tom A last comment. This post has been re-issued also on the NVIDIA forum [Parallel Anti diagonal 'for' loop](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/621875/parallel-anti-diagonal-for-loop/?offset=4). In that post, there are some inputs from njuffa and some clarifications from the poster. From the poster's clarifications, I understand he needs to do something "similar" to [Parallelizing the Smith-Waterman Local
Alignment Algorithm using CUDA](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/158/cudasw.pdf) (see Section 2.1).

Answer (score 1):

As long as I understand, you want something like

[Parallelizing the Smith-Waterman Local Alignment Algorithm using CUDA](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/158/cudasw.pdf) A

At each iteration, the kernel is launched with a different number of threads.

Perhaps the code in [Parallel Anti diagonal 'for' loop](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/621875/parallel-anti-diagonal-for-loop/?offset=5#3973588) could be modified as

```
int iDivUp(const int a, const int b) { return (a % b != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); };

#define BLOCKSIZE 32

__global__ antiparallel(float* d_A, int step, int N) {

    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x* blockDim.x;
    int j = step-i;

    /* do work on d_A[i*N+j] */

}

for (int step = 0; step < 2*N-1; step++) {
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCKSIZE);
    dim3 dimGrid(iDivUp(step,dimBlock.x));
    antiparallel<<<dimGrid.x,dimBlock.x>>>(d_A,step,N);
}
```

This code is untested and is just a sketch of a possible solution (provided that I have not misunderstood your question). Furthermore, I do not know how efficient would be a solution like that since you will have kernels launched with very few threads.